# Creating auto-correlated random values

Tags: random, time-series, correlation, lag

We are trying to create auto-correlated random values which will be used as timeseries.
We have no existing data we refer to and just want to create the vector from scratch.

On the one hand we need of course a random process with distribution and its SD.

On the other hand the autocorrelation influencing the random process has to be described. The values of the vector are autocorrelated with decreasing strengh over several timelags.
e.g. lag1 has 0.5, lag2 0.3, lag1 0.1 etc.

So in the end the vector should look something that:

```
2, 4, 7, 11, 10 , 8 , 5, 4, 2, -1, 2, 5, 9, 12, 13, 10, 8, 4, 3, 1, -2, -5
```

and so on.

Comment: Have you tried asking the same question over the Statistical Analysis exchange? ( http://stats.stackexchange.com/ )

Comment: Now, i did - and got a solution. The name of the thread is: ating auto-correlated random values in R. Anyone interested in the issue can look it up there

Comment: And here's the link so that you don't have to search for it... [http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29239/creating-auto-correlated-random-values-in-r](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29239/creating-auto-correlated-random-values-in-r)